# What assertion would I use for validating a list of dictionaries contains a specific value

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am new to unittest and still understanding how things work.  If I have a list of dictionaries...eg:

```
mylist = [{"y": "xval", "v": "x1val"}, 
          {"y": "yval", "v": "y1val"},
          {"y": "zval", "v": "z1val"}]
```

What sort of assertion/test would I perform to validate that the value for "v" is "y1val" when "y" = "yval"? It may also be the case that the dictionary y:yval does not exist in the list.

Comment: Couldn't you just test `{"y": "yval", "v": "y1val"} in mylist`?

Comment: What causes your assertion to fail: (1) the list contains no dictionary satisfying the requirement; (2) the list contains a dictionary that doesn't satisfy the requirement?  Also the requirement itself is complicated in that you must test the value of "y" before deciding whether to check "v".  You almost certainly will have to write a small function to implement this logic.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce solution seems good. Can you have multiple dict with 'yval' or is it unique?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce This would fail: `{"y": "yval", "v": "y1val", "a" : "aval"} although it satisfies the stated criterion.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Yes, for sure. That's why I phrased it as a question to try and get some clarification as to the specifics. Your example could happen but it also might never happen, who knows until OP clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no unittest assertion that can directly test that, but you can use a loop.

```
# This is inside a TestCase method
for d in mylist:
    if d['y'] == 'yval':
        self.assertEqual(d['v'], 'y1val')
```

This can be generalized to associate each `'y'` entry with an allowed `'v'` entry.

```
expected= {
    'xval': 'x1val',
    'yval': 'y1val',
    'zval': 'z1val'
}

# This is in a TestCase method
for d in mylist:
    self.assertEqual(d['v'], expected[d['y']])
```

Comment: I guess that kind of answers my question.  I was wondering if there was a way to create a single direct assertion to do this test.  It seems I have to wrap the assertion in some logic/loop to determine it it is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some schema validation module to validate your structure:

```
>>>from voluptuous import Schema

>>>Schema([{'y':str, 'v':str}])
>>> s([{"y": "xval", "v": "x1val"}, 
          {"y": "yval", "v": "y1val"},
          {"y": "zval", "v": "z1val"}])
[{'y': 'xval', 'v': 'x1val'}, {'y': 'yval', 'v': 'y1val'}, {'y': 'zval', 'v': 'z1val'}]
```

To install this module, you can use : pip install voluptuous